# Interpreting a simple linear mixed error model in R lmer

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme

I'm looking to understand this simple model in R:

m1 <- lmer(Y ~ exam_type + (1 + exam_type | subject ) )

Assume we have a dataset where:

- Y is numeric
- exam_type is a factor with 5 levels, let's say
- subject is also a factor, with many levels ( you can interpret this as a student id )

Specifically, could someone please explain:

- What are the assumptions of m1 above, compared, for example, with the following linear model:

---- m2 <- lm(Y ~ exam_type + subject + prev_test_score) ( assume prev_test_score is some other numerical variable).
I understand the assumptions of m2 : we assume there's a linear relationship between Y and all the features involved in the prediction, we assume errors are iid gaussian, and we simply estimate coefficients

- What does m1 estimate? It looks like it estimates coefficients, but just for exam_type. I'm confused because I thought that different subjects would have different coefficients for exam_type, in this formulation.

Thanks a lot for the help! Most important for me would be a clear formulation of the assumptions of the m1 formulation above, and what exactly we are estimating. Thanks a lot!